# iCloud and missing ubiquity-kvstore-identifier in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, icloud

im trying to test iCloud on my app for debugging purposes.

I can't get it to run on my iPad, as I understand it the problem is that I have no ubiquity-kvstore-identifier in my entitlements file. But the entitlements dictionary in the .entitlements file have to match exactly the one in the provisioning profile (the one you see using the "**security cms -D -i**" command).

When I attempt to use the service I get the error:

**NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: [bundle-id] has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement**

I have enabled iCloud for both my debugging provisioning profile and production in the provisioning profile manager (checked the box for iCloud that is).

I have removed the provisioning profiles in xcode and re-downloaded them (using the refresh function).

If I add the identifier manually to the .entitlements file it complains that the entitlements does not match the ones in the provisioning profile.

I don't get the error using simulator, but I guess it is because the simulator does not make the same certificate check as using an actual device?

Answer (score -1):

You can't test iCloud on simulator. You have test it actual device.